# cannot load such file in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I try use command: "`bundle install --without production`" and
"`rails g bootstrap:layout application fixed`" my rails application don't work

when i type anything command I get:

> /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in load': cannot load such file --
>   /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-4.1.8/bin/rails
>   (LoadError)   from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in '

I'm beginner in RoR and I can don't understand something. Please help me.
Sorry for my english:)

Comment: You need to be specific - we can only guess what you mean by "when I type any (sic) command I get"

Comment: for example if I type: $ rails s , console send's me this error's

Comment: sergey@sergeyvm1:~/devise$ rails s
                               /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-4.1.8/bin/rails (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
sergey@sergeyvm1:~/devise$

Comment: Are you in the project directory when you run `rails s`?

Comment: yes of course. Before everything worked

Comment: If you suspect the generate command, you can try `rails d bootstrap:layout application fixed` to undo it and see if that changes anything.  Also, try `bundle show` and see if that looks right, plus double check you have a proper `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: when I type command rails d bootstrap:layout application fixed, console again send's me this error. Don't work any commans with "rails" in all my projects. Bundle show:Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.1.8)
  * actionpack (4.1.8)
  * actionview (4.1.8)
  * activemodel (4.1.8)
  * activerecord (4.1.8)
  * activesupport (4.1.8)
  * arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
  * bcrypt (3.1.10)
  * builder (3.2.2)
  * bundler (1.10.5)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  * coffee-script (2.4.1)
  * coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
  * devise (3.5.1)
  * erubis (2.7.0)

Comment: * execjs (2.5.2)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.7.0)
  * jbuilder (2.3.1)
  * jquery-rails (3.1.3)
  * json (1.8.3)
  * mail (2.6.3)
  * mime-types (2.6.1)
  * minitest (5.7.0)
  * multi_json (1.11.2)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * rack (1.5.5)
  * rack-test (0.6.3)
  * rails (4.1.8)
  * railties (4.1.8)
  * rake (10.4.2)
  * rb-readline (0.5.3)
  * rdoc (4.2.0)
  * responders (1.1.2)
  * sass (3.2.19)
  * sass-rails (4.0.5)
  * sdoc (0.4.1)
  * spring (1.3.6)
  * sprockets (2.12.4)
  * sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.10)
  * thor (0.19.1)
  * thread_safe (0.3.5)

Comment: * tilt (1.4.1)
  * turbolinks (2.5.3)
  * tzinfo (1.2.2)
  * uglifier (2.7.1)
  * warden (1.2.3)

Comment: From what I've seen, this error usually points to a problem with your environment (rvm, Ruby, etc).  Maybe you can update your post with some details about how you have Ruby and Rails installed and what you are using for development environment.  You may need to reinstall components.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your gemfile

```
gem 'rb-readline'
```

and then try to install readline

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

i had and error like that before and that solved my problem

Comment: It doesn't work. The problem appears in all projects, not in any one